# Firestore keeps writing documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I broke my Firebase. It keeps writing documents to Firestore, how can I stop this? I using Cloud Functions but it cannot stop writing data to Firestore

EDIT: This is still an early app I'm developing so I just panic deleted the whole project. What could I do next time? Other than messing up in the first place

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I realized my error, I was writing a onCreate cloud function and foolishly allowed it to loop indefinitely. I'm asking for advice about if there is anything I could have done after the infinite loop started

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Firebase console and delete the function using the overflow menu (three dots on the far right).  That will stop it from executing.